# read first line of the file and compare it with a string in shell file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I need to read first line of a file and match it with a text. If the text matches, I need to do certain operation.

Problem is if command is unable to compare the variable with the string.

```
file_content=$(head -1 ${file_name})
echo $file_content
if [[ $file_content = 'No new data' ]]; then
    echo "Should come here"
fi
echo $file_content
if [ "${file_content}" = "No new data" ]; then
  echo "Should come here"
fi
```

The if block is not working.
I think the value that I am capturing in line 1 has some issues.

Comment: What does `printf '%s\n' "$file_content" | sed -n l` output?

Comment: No new data\r$    
What is this \r$ at the end? How to fix this.

Comment: You are using a Windows file.

Comment: Your script will work if you remove the `\r`. Just follow the instructions in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the first line contains non-printable characters or leading or trailing blanks or blank characters other than space (you forgot to quote the variable when passed to `echo`). You could also clean it up first:

```
content=$(
  sed '
    s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g; # turn sequences of spacing characters into one SPC
    s/[^[:print:]]//g; # remove non-printable characters
    s/^ //; s/ $//; # remove leading and trailing space
    q; # quit after first line' < "$file_name"
)

if [ "$content" = 'No new data' ]; then
  echo OK
fi
```

Comment: used
file_content="$(echo -e "${file_content_init}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"